# asp.net core WebApi issues after Visual Studio 2017 RC update

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-core-webapi

I've updated my Visual Studio 2017 to latest version (RC.4+26206.0) this morning since then my asp.net core api stopped working. 
In chrome I see error: `net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET` or if I run it on Kestrel instead of IIS Express I see `net::ERR_INCOMPLETE_CHUNKED_ENCODING`. 
I didn't change anything else.

Did anyone encounter this issue?

Comment: I just started getting this with no actual changes on my end. Just out of the blue some endpoints start throwing this error when clients call them.

Comment: If I remember correctly, I had to create a new asp.net core project and move all code to the new project. It was desperate man move, but it worked.